# Importação de módulos no PyCharm

Tags: python, importação, pycharm, import

Estou tentando importar módulos no PyCharm:

```
from mymodule import fileHandler
```

Contudo, a IDLE acusa o erro `ImportError: cannot import name FileHandle`

Já tentei seguir as sugestões mais comuns:

1. Identificar a pasta raiz como `src`;
2. Adicionar ao `PYTHONPATH` os fontes do passo anterior.

e nenhuma funcionou

Comment: No caso esse módulo é seu né?

Comment: Sim, os módulos que importo são meus.

Comment: você esta usando IDLE ou PyCharm?

Comment: Pycharm. Era pra ter escrito IDE

Answer (score 2):

Onde ficam os projetos, clica em com o botão direito "Mark directory as..." depois "Sources Root"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por "onde ficam os projetos" você diz pra clicar no nome do projeto?

Comment: Isso, na pasta com o nome do Projeto.