# ERRO DE IMPORTAÇÃO - No module named dlib

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, dll, inteligência-artificial, pycharm

Eu instalei o dlib, opencv e pillow por meio do Anaconda, criando um *enviroment*, porém quando eu vou importar o dlib acontece o seguinte erro: ***No module named dlib***. Eu já apaguei os interpretadores e os *enviroment* e refiz tudo novamente mas continua dando o mesmo erro.

Segue a imagem do erro: 
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não faço a mínima ideia de como resolver isso, já tentei de diversas formas e não consigo, nem os materiais que encontro na internet resolveram. O interpretador é esse:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como pode-se perceber, todas as bibliotecas ditas acima foram instaladas.

Answer (score 0):

No Pycharm basta ir até a pasta raiz do projeto e clicar com o botão direito > Mark Directory as > Sources Root. que isso resolverá.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Problema resolvido em: [Importação de módulos no PyCharm](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/264426/importa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-de-m%C3%B3dulos-no-pycharm)